# Is there anyway for a bash (or any other shell) script to detect whether the current terminal supports unicode characters?

Tags: bash, shell, unicode, zsh

I'd like to use Unicode characters if they are supported by the terminal, and fall back to ASCII characters if the user's terminal can't display them correctly.  Is there any relatively easy way to do this in a shell script?

Answer (score 3):

First, you're probably confusing Unicode with a particular encoding. Suppose you know that the termnal supports Unicode characters -- you still don't know how to print them!

You're probably thinking about something like UTF-8, the most popular Unicode encoding out there.

To get the encoding of the current locale, use

```
locale charmap
```

This is the encoding of the current *locale*, and theoretically it may differ from the encoding used by the terminal, but in that case something is broken on user's side.

Comment: How would it be possible to know that a terminal supports unicode without knowing the specific set?  This information is helpful, but your accusation of confusion is odd in the least.

Answer (score -1):

In script print

:set encoding=utf-8

If you want your terminal support unicode, become new terminal with -u8 option

type in terminal **xterm -u8**

Comment: First, never suggest somebody to touch `encoding` option somewhere outside vimrc: it can be changed without causing bugs only before vim reads any unicode string into memory. Second, *become new terminal with -u8 option* is terminal specific: for example, `konsole` does not accept this and for xterm it is probably better to do `echo "xterm*utf-8: 4" >> ~/.Xresources`.